# FME GeometryReplacer, WKT Error

Tags: point, fme-form, well-known-text, fme-transformer

I am trying to load POINT WKT Geometry from MS SQL Server, it is in WKT Format. Using the GeometryReplacer, I am receiving an Error, and everything looks right as far as I can see, it continues to reject the Geometry.

Examples from my WKT GEOMETRY Field "POINT (-78.890394956 38.069839405)" "POINT (-79.9038433969999 37.359853302)" etc

Rejection Error from FME
Invalid WKT encountered: P

... Last line repeated 11856 times ..

rejection CODE:
INVALID_PARAMETER_GEOMETRY_SOURCE

[image]

Comment: Your coordinates are the wrong way around from MS SQL.

Comment: WKT is supposed to be (long, lat)?

Comment: there is no strict standard https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2007/12/lets-call-whole-thing-off.html

Comment: Still, it would be plotting them regardless in Antarctica or thereabouts, even if the coordinates were reversed, I don't think that's the cause of the error I'm getting, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use a 32-bit Version of FME, and it worked.